# Why this space crashes the javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have this code, which works perfectly to replace stuff in some divs (the example is actually at http://wiki-es.guildwars2.com/wiki/Reemplazador_Wiki, click on the red "AQUI" to see a live demonstration).

```
$("#SaeReplacerButton").dblclick(function () {
    document.getElementById("SaeReplacerResult").innerHTML = "Error";
    var TextoInicial = document.getElementById("SaeReplacerInput").innerHTML;
    var Reemplazos = {
        quemadura: "{{quemadura}}",
        incapacitar: "{{incapacitar}}",
        inmovilizar: "{{inmovilizar}}",
        égida: "{{égida}}",
        furia: "{{furia}}",
        poder: "{{poder}}",
        protección: "{{protección}}",
        regeneración: "{{regeneración}}",
        represalia: "{{represalia}}",
        celeridad: "{{celeridad}}",
        vigor: "{{vigor}}",
        Primordus: "[[Primordus]]",
        Kralkatorrik: "[[Kralkatorrik]]",
        Guerrero: "{{guerrero}} [[Guerrero]]",
        Guardián: "{{guardián}} [[Guardián]]",
        Retornado: "{{retornado}}[[Retornado]]",
        Elementalista: "{{elementalista}} [[Elementalista]]",
        Guardabosques: "{{guardabosques}} [[Guardabosques]]",
        Ingeniero: "{{ingeniero}} [[Ingeniero]]",
        Nigromante: "{{nigromante}} [[Nigromante]]",
        Ladrón: "{{ladrón}} [[Ladrón]]",
        Hipnotizador: "{{hipnotizador}} [[Hipnotizador]]"
    }
    for (key in Reemplazos) {
        var TextoInicial = TextoInicial.replace(key, Reemplazos[key]);
    };
    document.getElementById("SaeReplacerResult").innerHTML = TextoInicial;
});
```

However the problem starts if I change:

```
Retornado:"{{retornado}}[[Retornado]]",
```

for this:

```
Retornado:"{{retornado}} [[Retornado]]",
```

As you can see, I just added an space, which shouldn't matter at all because all the other arrays replacement works. However when I add that space to the Retornado one, the entire function stops working.
The question is: Why?

Comment: Where is this templating happening. on the server side?

Comment: @robert-moskal, Yes, it's on the server side. **Edit:** In case you need to check, the code is actually at http://wiki-es.guildwars2.com/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.js

Comment: @Saelyth: in fact, there is no templating happening in `.js` files on mediawiki.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "entire function stops working". What does happen? Do you get any errors?

Comment: To be honest, I'm quite a noob about javascript or .js files, hence that's why I come to ask you guys. Sorry for that. **Edit:** @Bergi It gives no errors at all, I just double click and it literally does nothing. It's like if the function wouldn't exists anymore.

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/g88xjfzx/ Please create a minimal demonstration here that accurately reproduces the issue.